# Performance of Long Primary Keys

Tags: performance, index, security, primary-key, hashing

There are plenty of discussions on the benefits and drawbacks of using hashes as primary keys, but in my case I have a database of webpages that I need to look up by address, and these addresses are longer than the maximum text index length.  Also, it's quite the performance hit to index on `varchar`.

Until recently I was using MD5 checksums to look up addresses due to the speed of the function and a limited need for protection against hash collisions.  But this specific application has the potential for the submission of "database-malicious URLs" that are invalid*, but crafted with the same checksum as valid URLs.

Is there a big performance hit switching from a primary key using 128-bit MD5 to a primary key of SHA-224+ ([the smallest "unbroken" SHA-based hash I can find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm))?  Should I index these as byte arrays or chars?  Or is there another solution if I need reverse lookup AND collision security?

My DBMS is MySQL 5.7, but I would consider switching if there's an amazing solution in another DBMS with similar resource requirements that is freely available.

*Invalid as in technically resolvable, but not a "real" URL, i.e. http://example.com/reallyLongStringThatYieldsAHashCollisionWithARealURL

Comment: What if you store first few characters of url (as a new column) in addition to  md5 ?  It will make it practically impossible to generate malicious URL.

Comment: If I append the first 8 characters of the domain name and the first 8 characters of the path, that takes me from a 16-byte MD5 hash to a 32-byte string, at which point I may as well use the 32-byte SHA-256 or the 28-byte SHA-224, if my math is correct.

Comment: What database?  A url is too long to be indexed?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, a URL is too long to be indexed.  A URL is essentially a `varchar(2000)` based on web browser expectations (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)), and to maintain compatibility I need to store that theoretical maximum.  According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157227/mysql-varchar-index-length) the maximum number of characters indexed by a varchar is 766.  And yes, I have come across URLs that are longer than 766 characters.

Comment: Oh, so the database is MSSQL.  The answer would be database dependent.   That is why I ask what database?

Comment: @Paparazzi Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment.  MySQL currently, although I would consider switching backends if there were a DBMS that solved the problem and had similar resource requirements (and was free-to-use).  I will add this to the question.

Comment: Why not just test  SHA-224 with you data?

Comment: My old data has been invalidated and I'm re-writing the backend, hence my ability to change primary keys on-the-fly.  But I still have my old data set (archived at the moment) and running a few tests should prove interesting.  I'll try to do just that within the next week and I'll post an answer when I do.